# How to implement slicing in docplex?

Tags: docplex

I'm transferring some code from OPL to docplex and I'm having troubles with the syntax for slicing. I'm attempting to create a set of constraints with a summation over all values with connection to another decision variable.

I've tried both `add_constraints` and `add_constraint` (inside a for loop) but I'm getting an invalid syntax error. I used this format with Google OR so I'd expected this to work.

Here's my OPL code:

```
forall(<var1,var3> in Index2)
        sum(<var1,var2,var3> in Index1) 
            dev_var[var1,var2,var3] == cec_var2[<var1,var3>];
```

I tried the following in docplex:

```
for row2 in df1.itertuples():
    solver.add_constraint(solver.sum(dec_var[row.var1,row.var2,row.var3] 
       for row in df2.itertuples()) == dec_var2[row2.var1,row2.var3] 
           if row2.var1 = row.var1 and row2.var3 = row.var3)
```

I'm expecting to create a constraint for each `var1,var3` combination that includes all relevant indexes of `var1,var2,var3` found in the other index/dataframe. With the "if" statement included, I get a "invalid syntax" error, but without it I get constraints that include a full Cartesian join of the other index without any filtering.

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statement, did you try using `==` (equality operator) instead of `=` (assignment operator)? I'm not sure that python/pandas like assignments in the conditional expression.

Comment: You're right that I needed to use the proper double == to get the syntax to work. It now is working as: solver.add_constraints(solver.sum(dec_var[row.var1,row.var2,row.var3] for row in index.itertuples() if row.var1 == row2.var1 and row.var3 == row2.var3) ==dec_var2[row2.var1,row2.var3] for row2 in index2.itertuples())

Comment: BUT it is about 8 times slower than creating the forall index myself, i.e., 
for row2 in index.itertuples():
    index2 = index.loc[(index['var1'] ==row2.var1) & (index['var3'] == row2.var3)]    
    solver.add_constraint(solver.sum(dec_var[row.var1,row,var2,row,var3] for row in index2.itertuples()) ==dec_var2[row2.var1,row2.var3])

Answer (score 0):

```
for var1 in index2:
    for var3 in index2:
        model.add_constraint(model.sum(model.sum(model.sum(dev_var[a,b,c] for a in index1) for b in index1) for c in index1) == cec_var2[var1,var3])
```

there is something wrong，hope a little help for you

Comment: This approach won't work because I'm doing slicing on the indices and not a full Cartesian join across all a, b and c.